# How can I stop webChromeClient from opening files in the Android Browser

Tags: java, android, html, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I am developing an Android App using WebView which loads a locally stored HTML5/JQuery Mobile app in the assets folder.  The App gets content from a REST service on a domain I own.  The content is a mixture of HTML content and downloadable files.

My problem lies when a user clicks on a button to download a file, a Browser window launches and the file is downloaded, which is great.  However my App then loses focus and I have a blank browser on screen.  I have done a bit of Googling and have read a few answers on Stack Overflow and have adapted my code to set a Download Listener, but this still loads the Browser.  Please advise.  My code is listed below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Android DownloadManager (please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) instead of starting a VIEW Intent? I think that you'd just need to enqueue a download from your DownloadListener.